# JSoup not parsing a <div>. Everything else is getting parsed

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

So i was working with JSoup and tried to parse this website:

http://www.sportstats.com/soccer/germany/bundesliga/

I tried to get at least the first `<div class = clubTable>` which holds the upcoming matches for the next 3 days.

This is my Code:

```
    try{
        url = new URL("http://www.sportstats.com/soccer/germany/bundesliga/");
        doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3 * 1000);
    }catch(MalformedURLException ie){
        System.out.println(ie);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    Elements links = doc.select("div > div.tableShadow");
    System.out.println(links);
```

My Output is this:

```
<div class="tableShadow" id="LS_nextMatchesContent"></div>
```

The thing is, that between this `<div>` there should be the whole table (as you may have already seen if you took a look at the HTML-Code of the website). But it's not showing up when i parse the website.
It also wasn't showing when i tried to select the specific `<div>`.

I am not really into JSoup so if anyone has an idea on how to fix this i would be happy to hear it.

Comment: It isn't there. One of the common mistakes when using JSoup is to think that data filled in by Javascript is part of the page. But if you look at the source of the page using "view page source" rather than FireBug/Browser tools, you'll see the div is empty. So JSoup will not get that data for you.

Comment: Yep i just figured out the same thing, but thanks for the fast answer! I used the "Inspect Element" Tool provided by Google Chrome though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSoup does not interpret JavaScript, so when a website loads data via AJAX call Jsoup will not get it automatically. Two approaches might lead you to the desired result:

1. Use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) together with a real browser, HTMLUnit or phantomjs. This will most likely work, but may be slow.
2. Identify the AJAX calls, find out about the API and use this knowledge to build the same http request by hand. For this you can keep using Jsoup, although a more powerful HTTP library like [Apache httpClient](http://hc.apache.org/) may be of help.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! I'll look how i can use this.